# Url Rewrite Provider on Azure Web App

Tags: asp.net, azure, url-rewriting, azure-web-app-service, url-rewrite-module

We use the DbProvider from the [URL Rewrite Extensibility Samples](http://www.iis.net/learn/extensions/url-rewrite-module/using-custom-rewrite-providers-with-url-rewrite-module) for allow our rewrite rules to use db values. I'm trying to move this website to an Azure Web App. After deploying to a Windows Azure Web App, I'm getting this error:

```
HTTP Error 500.50 - URL Rewrite Module Error.
System.IO.FileNotFoundException: Could not load file or assembly
 'Microsoft.Web.Iis.Rewrite.Providers, Version=7.1.761.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=0545b0627da60a5f' 
or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified. 
File name: 'Microsoft.Web.Iis.Rewrite.Providers, Version=7.1.761.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=0545b0627da60a5f'
```

How do I install what's necessary on the Azure Web App to allow this to work since I can't install the URL Rewrite Extensibility Samples directly, nor would I want to.

Comment: *Please* go back and edit your question to properly format that error dump. As posted, it's unreadable.

Answer (score 0):

You can't install something on a Web App unless it's packaged as an Extension (see: https://www.siteextensions.net/). I don't see those providers as being packaged so you'd have to create a package yourself or look for an alternative solution.

Having said this, you could try package the assemblies in a Web App you deploy and see if that works as expected (it's not something I've tried in this exact scenario).

Comment: Unfortunately, it does not work to put the DLLs right in the project. I believe IIS requires them earlier in the pipeline.

Answer (score 0):

It may be hacky, but you could try pulling the DLL and its depencies into your BIN folder and deploy.  You don't get the nice UI to manage, but worth a shot.

Comment: I did try this, and it didn't work. I believe IIS needs them earlier in the pipeline.